# How to get the language name of OS

Tags: visual-c++

Hi how to get the language name,how to find the language that the OS is installed say eg : If the OS is Japaness then i should display the language "Japanness"

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN you need to use [GetUserDefaultLCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318135(VS.85).aspx) function for this.

Comment: hi plz will give me a sample code that i can get more clear,any example

Comment: I think you mean `GetUserDefaultLocaleName()`. The LCID one won't give you a _name_ but a _number_. `GetUserDefaultLocaleName()` will directly put the locale name into the buffer provided.

Answer (score 0):

"Globalization Step-by-Step" Section "Retrieving the User Locale in Win32"
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688121.aspx)